# HTTP IMAGE REQUEST ANDROID

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have loaded an image to my image view from an image URL using Picasso library.. But i want the image to be updated in my app anytime i change the image on my website... Please help me out.

Comment: do you have code on how you're requesting the image, and how the images are being displayed right now?

Comment: yes i have a code for that

Comment: public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view=  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, container, false);
        ImageButton newsbut=(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.newsbut);
        Picasso.with(getContext()).load("https://static.wixstatic.com/media/68e522_523c41242d13446ebdcb5768e74555ac~mv2.png/v1/fill/w_448,h_796,al_c,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/68e522_523c41242d13446ebdcb5768e74555ac~mv2.png").into(newsbut);
        return view;
    }

Answer (score 1):

If you are using fragment

```
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load("http://example.com/image.jpg").into(imageView);
```

or with activity

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://example.com/image.jpg").into(imageView);
```

Now on your website make sure you are changing image with same name and extension like in this case its 'image.jpg'

Comment: Ok sir.. i will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Try the following `pseudocode` :

```
....
/* create a service that runs in the background every n amount of time*/

/* create a simple http request to your server to check if there are changes */

/* if changed == true; then simply notify the activity or whatever you are using */

/* to reload the imageView by calling the Picasso method accordingly */

/* If the image URL is changed, you can get that from your http request and simply set it to the Picasso method that downloads the image */

/* What I would do is use an Event to seamlessly notify the activity or fragment to update image view */
```

I hope this gives you an idea. Good luck!